# What are some wget URL security checks?

Tags: ruby, security, wget

I'm using Ruby's [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method.

```
system("/bin/wget", "-pk", "-nd", "-P", "/public/download", "#{URL}")
```

where `URL` is filled in by the user.

What checks should I perform on the server against `URL` to make sure that the user is not doing something malicious?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `wget`? I'm fairly certain there are ways to do this in Ruby, and probably even a `curl` binding if you don't want to write it all by yourself. If this is only meant to work on systems with `wget` installed in `/bin/` it's perfectly fine, but I was wondering.

Comment: @EsaLakaniemi Thanks for your concern. I'm using `wget` mainly because of it allows for those options I put in as arguments; if there are other ways to achieve the same thing, I'd be happy to hear. The code will only run on my server, which has `wget` installed in `/bin/`.

Comment: Do you perform any checks on the entered URL?

Comment: @Gumbo I'm not, and that's exactly my question -- what check(s) should I perform on the entered URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that in the way you've called it, you don't have to worry about someone passing in say `; rm -rf *`.  However, if wget does anything special to the URL you might.  For example, curl lets you do some regex/range/wildcard stuff in the URL itself.

You might consider running URL through `URI.parse` and catch `URI::InvalidURIError`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Philip. As this is an open-ended question, I'd like to keep the thread open for now in case people have other ideas.